# Developing a case tool in visual studio 2017

Tags: vb.net

I am currently developing a case tool in visual studio 2017 in VB where users can design entities and relationship(lines). For designing the entity box, I have used a picturebox and a richtextbox on top and I want that when I am dragging the picturebox, I want the richtextbox to stay with the picturebox. I think the 2 controls(picturebox and the richtextbox) must act as one control but I am not able to do so.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to put them both in one UserControl.

Comment: Further to Craig's comment, you add a user control to your project in basically the same way you add a form. You then design and code it the same way too. Once you build, your user control will be added to the Toolbox automatically and you can then use it like any other control. I would advise you to declare the child controls private and then provide pass-through members for only those members of the child controls that you need on the outside, e.g. an `Image` property that gets and sets the `image` property of the `PictureBox`.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me get my job done